# mysql workbench not start after installed in ubuntu software 18.04

Tags: software-center, 18.04, mysql-workbench

I installed the mysql workbench through Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 18.04. When I clicked the mysql workbench icon in launcher, it can't open. so I try terminal, but fails. I googled it, but i didn't find it. Please guide me to solve the issue.

```
tamil@tamilcselvan:~$ sudo mysql-workbench 
[sudo] password for tamil: 
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libsigc-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also searched the missing libraries:

```
tamil@tamilcselvan:~$ sudo apt install libsigc-2.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsigc-2.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libsigc-2.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libsigc-2.0'
```